# Can HttpServerUtility.Execute get binary data?

Tags: asp.net, httpcontext, httpserverutility

This is how I normally execute an aspx web form and get a string from the output:

```
public static string GetAspPageOutput(string page)
{
  string html;

  using (var sw = new StringWriter())
  {
    HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, sw);

    html = sw.ToString();
  }

  return html;
}
```

How do I instead get a byte array?

Comment: Is the page writing a binary response? Or are you wanting to convert this HTML to a byte array?

Comment: Yes, the page is using `HttpResponse.BinaryWrite`.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion is from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/1745456/3646986. Use the StreamWriter instead of the StringWriter

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ms);
context.Server.Execute(virtualpath, writer);
var bytes = ms.toArray()
return bytes
```